# HTTP/HTTPS response methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, request

I am learning Node.js and stumbled upon this snippet from https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

```
 const req = await https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
 });
```

I don't get the on "data" method.. where does it come from? why not on "info"? I see there is on "error", are there more? where can I find documentation about it?

Comment: FWIW, that code doesn't exist on [the page you linked](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html). Which is good, because it doesn't make sense to `await` `https.request` as it doesn't return a promise.

Comment: `"data"` isn't a method, it is an event name. We can't tell you why the designers of the API picked a particular name for something.

Comment: It's harder to follow the documentation for this stuff than it should be.

Comment: why do you use await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is the name of the event that the response emits when it has data that you can read from the response. The event is fired as many time as necessary to transfer all the data; then an `end` event is fired.

> where does it come from?

The response to the request (ultimately, from the other end of the conversation).

> why not on "info"?

Or `"block"` or `"packet"` or... Because the person designing the API had to pick a name, and picked `"data"`.

> I see there is on "error", are there more?

Yes.

> where can I find documentation about it?

This isn't as obvious as it could be. The documentatihon for `https.request` is on [the page you linked](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback), but doesn't directly mention the `data` event. It's the HTTPS version of [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), which says:

> The optional callback parameter will be added as a one-time listener for the ['response'](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response) event.

Following that tells you that the response object (`res`) is an [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) object, which is a [readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), which documents its various events, including [`data`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data).